# How to get list([a,2],[a,1],[a,3]) with the highest number([a,3])

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a

```
list=[[a,2],[a,1],[a,3],[b,5],[b,7],[b,6],[c,20],[c,23],[c,30]].
```

How do I get the list of the highest number for each letter? And that list append it to another list containing the highest number for each letter?

I have tried using the following code, but im a new to programming in python and I dont know much about data structures or programming.

```py
for letter in range(len(final)):
    array1=[]
    array2=[]
    highestvalue=0
    if final[letter][0] == final[letter+1][0]:
        if final[letter][2] < final[letter+1][2]:
            highestvalue=final[letter+1][2]
            array1.append(final[letter][0])
            array1.append(highestvalue)
            array2.append(array1)
```

Is there a way to get [[a,3],[b,7],[c,30]] out of list?

[EDIT]
Actually, my list is [[a,abc,2],[a,def,1],[a,ghi,3],[b,jkl,5],[b,lmn,7],[b,opq,6],[c,rst,20],[c,vwx,23],[c,yzz,30]].

What I expect is create a list that store the variables [[a,ghi,3],[b,lmn,7],[c,yzz,30]]. How can I create the list with the second element, along with the letter and the max value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tag `pandas`

```
pd.DataFrame(l).groupby(0).max().reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[535]: [['a', 3], ['b', 7], ['c', 30]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the sublists by the letters and look for the maximum within each group:

```
from operator import itemgetter as g
from itertools import groupby

[max(v, key=g(1)) for k, v in groupby(l, g(0))]
# [['a', 3], ['b', 7], ['c', 30]]
```

Comment: You're already using `itemgetter`, go to town `from operator import itemgetter as g; from itertools import groupby; [max(v, key=g(1)) for k, v in groupby(l, g(0))]`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> foo = [['a', 2],['a', 1],['a', 3],
           ['b', 5],['b', 7],['b', 6],
           ['c', 20],['c', 23],['c', 30]]
>>> print({key:value for key, value in sorted(foo)})
{'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 30}
```

Comment: this should do `[*map(list, dict(sorted(foo)).items())]`

Comment: Ahh nice idea using sorted here

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with simple Python generators:

```
lst=[['a',2],['a',1],['a',3],['b',5],['b',7],['b',6],['c',20],['c',23],['c',30]]
[max(filter(lambda x: x[0] == elem, lst), key=lambda x: x[1]) for elem in set([e[0] for e in lst])]
```

will return you:

`[['c', 30], ['b', 7], ['a', 3]]`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a place to store (a dictionary) the highest value encountered for each letter.

Then go through the list , and compare the value you have in storage against the new value for the letter.

```
list=[[a,2],[a,1],[a,3],[b,5],[b,7],[b,6],[c,20],[c,23],[c,30]]
storing_maximum={}
for x,y in list:
    if x in storing_maximum:
        storing_maximum[x] = max(storing_maximum[x],y)
    else:
        storing_maximum[x] = y
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, separate your list into separate lists, one for each letter.
Then build a list of the second elements and take the `max` of that.

Another possibility is to build a `dict` keyed by the letter; the value of each element is the max value you've seen for that letter.

Can you take it form there?  If not, I recommend working through the logic with someone local, as Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(l).sort_values([0, 2]).drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep='last').values.tolist()

Out[23]: [['a', 'ghi', 3], ['b', 'lmn', 7], ['c', 'yzz', 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store your temporary maximum in a dictionary. That way you would still be able to solve it with [`O(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) complexity. Have a look at this quick example:

```py
mylist = [['a','abc',2],['a','def',1],['a','ghi',3],['b','jkl',5],['b','lmn',7],['b','opq',6],['c','rst',20],['c','vwx',23],['c','yzz',30]]

myres = []
mymax = {}

for l in mylist:
    # corresponds to 'a', 'b', 'c', ...
    k = l[0]

    # if your identifier is not already stored
    # or the last value of your array is greater than the one that is already stored
    if not k in mymax or l[-1] > mymax[k][-1]:
        # apply a new maximum
        # *after first iteration it holds -> {'a': ['a','abc',2]}
        mymax[k] = l

# is used to convert back to a list, you may as well skip it if not needed
for _, v in mymax.items():
    myres.append(v)

# prints [['a', 'ghi', 3], ['b', 'lmn', 7], ['c', 'yzz', 30]]
print(myres)
```

I hope that helps!